# calculating event duration in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I am attempting to reference this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352279/calculating-the-duration-an-event-in-a-time-series-python) where the first answer someone creates some code to analyze the time series data of rain fall and totalize in hours for each rain event. I want to do something similar except for totalizing how often a pump runs (event) in hours each day from time series data. There is no need on my end for totalizing anything else just the duration of the event.

```
#read CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\desktop\\data.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

# Converting the index as date
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df
```

My data looks like this:

```
                    ChWaterPrs
Date                                                                    
1/0/00 12:45 AM          0.0
1/0/00 12:50 AM          0.0
1/0/00 12:55 AM          0.0
1/0/00 12:00 AM          0.0
1/0/00 1:05 AM           0.0
```

I know that the pump is running everytime the `df['ChWaterPrs']` is greater than 5, so I am attempting to build these helper colums as mentioned in the SO post:

```
# create helper columns, a block would be anytime value is > 5
df['block'] = df['ChWaterPrs'] >= 5
df['day'] = df.index.normalize()

# group by day to get unique block count and value count
session_map = df[df['ChWaterPrs'].astype(bool)].groupby('day')['block'].nunique()
hour_map = df[df['ChWaterPrs'].astype(bool)].groupby('day')['ChWaterPrs'].count()

# map to original dataframe
df['sessions'] = df['day'].map(session_map)
df['hours'] = df['day'].map(hour_map)

# calculate result
res = df.groupby(['day', 'hours', 'sessions'], as_index=False)['ChWaterPrs'].sum()
res['duration'] = res['hours'] / res['sessions']
res['amount'] = res['ChWaterPrs'] / res['sessions']
```

But if I print `res` something is screwed up... The durations don't make sense that they are greater than 24 hours in a day. Basically the only information I would love to have is a `resample` of the time series data for how many `hours` that the pump ran which is determined by the `df['ChWaterPrs']` being greater than 5. I think the data would show everyday (a session) where the `df['ChWaterPrs']` would be zero else greater than 5 when running. Any tips help thank you.

[image]

Comment: This date looks messed up: `1/0/00 12:45 AM`

Comment: Yes, something happened to my CSV file which made it corrupt and I had to retrieve a new set of data which looks more like the screen shot.

Comment: It is in 5 minute intervals tho, a years worth of time series data